# Python Game of War using functions

Tags: python, loops

I have to complete this assignment, below is what I have so far and I have attached a picture of what the output should look like. I am not very good with functions and am not sure if this program is formatted correctly or how to call the functions to get them to run the game.

For this assignment, you are going to be creating a more realistic "Game of War".

Your program should do the follow:

- Introduce how the game will be played
- Play 10 rounds
- Each round, display the card that player 1 drew, and the card player 2 drew
- Determine who won, or if it was a draw - and display that
- Wait 2 seconds between rounds
- At the end of each round, display the final scores, and display "XYZ won!!"

Requirements:

1. Create a function called getCardValue with the following prototype "def getCardValue()" that returns a single random number between 2 and 14. Use randint() in this function to get a random number.
2. Create a function called displayCardValue with the following prototype "def displayCardValue(value)" that returns the string version of the card value. That is, 11 = J, 12 = Q, 13 = K, 14 = A, and all other numbers are converted to strings.
3. Make a function called determineMax with the following prototype: "def determineMax(a, b)" This function will return 1 if a is greater than b, otherwise if return 2 if a less than b, otherwise return 0. Use this function to determine the winner of each round and the winner of the whole game at the end.
4. Create a function called playRound() with the following prototype "def playRound()"
   that returns the winner of the round. Use this function to simplify the main game loop. Keep track of the player's scores in the main loop.
5. Write the main game loop at the global level (or use an ifmain + main() function). Here you should keep track of the player's points, display the game text, and determine/display the final winner using the functions written in the above parts. Make the game feel natural. Add a short introduction at the start of the program. Use the sleep() function from the time class to pause the screen output for a short time after each round.

   ```
    import random
    import time

    def main():
        print("Welcome to the Game of War!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("The player who draws the higher card wins the round.")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Whoever has more points at the end of 10 rounds wins the game! Here we 
        go!")
        time.sleep(4)
        print()


       num_rounds = 10
       wins_player1 = 0
       wins_player2 = 0

       def getCardValue():
           card1 = random.randint(2,15)

      def displayCardValue(value):
          if card1 == 11:
              return "J"
          elif card1 == 12:
             return "Q"
          elif card1 == 13:
             return "K"
          elif card1 == 14:
             return "A"
          else:
             return str(card1)

      def determineMax(a, b):
          a = getCardValue
          b = getCardValue
          if a > b:
              return 1
              wins_player1 += 1
          elif a < b:
              return 2
              wins_player2 += 1
          else:
              return 0

      def playRound():

      for i in range(10):
          print('------- ROUND',(i+1),'-------')

    if __name__ == "__main__":                                                              
        main()
   ```

[image: What output should look like]

Comment: Your functions need to be defined before you start the loop, and CALLED inside the loop.  As it is, your loop doesn't DO anything.  You define the functions 10 times, but you never call them.  And `getCardValue` needs to return the ONE value it created.  You are fetching two random numbers, and then throwing them away.

Comment: Slow down and reread the chapter in your book on functions. They're not some magic thing that you wrap code in because people say "functions are good". They're a new language feature and you have to learn how to use them independent of everything else. Make sure you understand that and how to write simple functions before trying to combine them with other things like control flow and loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hesitated to do this, because you haven't really done very much on your own, but you did at least make an effort.  I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings of functions.  So don't just turn this in and take credit for it.  Instead, read what I've done here to see HOW the functions interact.  A function should have one purpose.  It transforms inputs into outputs.  It takes an input (through arguments), it does something to those inputs, and it returns an output.  The caller of the function then needs to do something with the output.

For example, `getCardValue` doesn't need to know there are two players.  It's job is just to return a new card.  The CALLER decides how to use that.  Same with `displayCardValue`.  It displays the value of the card it was given -- it doesn't know there's a game in progress, and it doesn't know how many players there are.

```
import random
import time

def getCardValue():
    return random.randrange(2,14)

def displayCardValue(value):
    if value > 10:
        return "JQKA"[value-11]
    return str(value)

def determineMax(a, b):
   if a > b:
       return 1
   elif a < b:
       return 2
   return 0

def playRound():
    card1 = getCardValue()
    card2 = getCardValue()
    print( "Player 1:", displayCardValue(card1), " | Player 2:", displayCardValue(card2))
    result = determineMax(card1, card2)
    if result == 1:
        print( "   Player 1 wins!" )
    elif result == 2:
        print( "   Player 2 wins!" )
    else:
        print( "   Tie!" )
    return result

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Game of War!")
    print("The player who draws the higher card wins the round.")
    print("Whoever has more points at the end of 10 rounds wins the game! Here we go!")
    print()

    num_rounds = 10
    wins_player1 = 0
    wins_player2 = 0

    for i in range(10):
        print('------ ROUND', i+1, '------')
        result = playRound()
        if result == 1:
            wins_player1 += 1
        else:
            wins_player2 += 1
        time.sleep(2)

    if wins_player1 > wins_player2:
        print( "   Player 1 wins the game!" )
    elif wins_player1 < wins_player2:
        print( "   Player 2 wins the game!" )
    else:
        print( "   It's a tie!")

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                              
     main()
```